# escaping backslash and bracket on windows awk

Tags: windows, awk

I have an `awk` command that I want to use on `cmd`. The following command works well in `bash`, but fails on windows `cmd`:

```
echo errr | awk '/err/ { $0 = "\033[32m" $0 "\033[39m" }; 1'
```

I get the following error on windows:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: '/err/
awk: cmd. line:1: ^ invalid char ''' in expression
```

After going through some questions, I changed my command to:

```
 echo errr | awk "/err/ { $0 = "\033[32m" $0 "\033[39m" }; 1"
```

but that gives me:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: /err/ { $0 = \033[32m $0 \033[39m }; 1
awk: cmd. line:1:              ^ backslash not last character on line
awk: cmd. line:1: /err/ { $0 = \033[32m $0 \033[39m }; 1
awk: cmd. line:1:              ^ syntax error
```

How can I port my command to work in `cmd`?

Comment: What version of windows do you use? It depends on whether cmd handles ANSI escape characters and how it does it. See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code in the Windows section.
Only when this issue is established is the sense of matching the AWK command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard advice when running awk on Windows:

a) don't do it, install cygwin and run awk from there instead

b) if "a" is not possible then create a file "foo.awk", store your script `/err/ { $0 = "\033[32m" $0 "\033[39m" }; 1` in that, and then run it as `awk -f foo.awk` to avoid Windows nightmarish quoting rules.

Comment: Thank you! Believe me, I don't want to run it Windows but in this situation I kind of need to. Your advise worked for me

Answer (score 1):

instead of awk 'your commands' use awk -e 'your commands', there should be no error. I do not have windows to check. Will it be coloring the text? Read my comment below your question.

EDIT:
OK, now if you have version 6 in PowerShell, it should work coloring like this:

```
echo errr | awk -e "/err/ { $0 = '`e[32m' $0 '`e[39m'}; 1 "
```

If you have a different version windows, look for the correct escape sequence in the link I provided.

Comment: It returns the same error with the -e flag. Yes I am trying to color the text

Comment: check which version you have awk: awk -V
enter in cmd: awk -e '// {print "Hello"}' [ENTER]
any text [ENTER]
wrote "Hello" do you have an error?

Comment: I have AWK 4.2.1 So awk -e '// {print "Hello"}' returns an error : awk: cmd. line:1: '//
awk: cmd. line:1: ^ invalid char ''' in expression

Comment: I replaced the single quotes with double quotes and then it waited for an input I guess.. after typing it didn't exit. I had to abort.

Comment: I do not think I understood. I do not have windows so I can not give a cooked one, sorry. If you have double quotes work then check:
echo errr | awk -e "/ err / {print 'Hello'}"
it works?

Comment: I think the issue still is that the single quotes do not work on cmd.exe (as suggested in your edited answer). Also the square bracket needs to be escaped somehow. So I think I am back to figuring out how to escape the [ and \ in awk

Comment: Without windows and awk in exactly the same version as yours I can not reproduce the problem, and guessing will last forever. This is not the answer, but for these reasons I do not use Windows, because it would seem simple tasks are the way through hell. Sorry.